# Python PyVirtualDisplay seems to do nothing now

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, pyvirtualdisplay

(I did post this before however I am new here and it was not the best example of the issue so I have deleted that post and made this one. I hope is clearer and more streamlined).

Essentially I had a Pi that ran headless perfectly via Selenium and PyVirtualDisplay however that SD card got fried and so I had to restart. This time however PyVirtualDisplay seems to do nothing as in even though I use it with visible=0 (see below) it still opens a new window and runs selenium as if there is no virtual display in other words selenium does not seem to use it. I am also trying not to use the chrome --headless option as I had it working fine without this before and it seems to cause more issues then solutions
Unkown
This time around i have made just a small program to test and attempt to get pyvirtual to work again so here is that entire code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

with Display(visible=0, size=(1600, 1200)):
    

    service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    website2 = "https://www.matchbook.com" 
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) 
    driver.get(website2)
    driver.maximize_window()

    test = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a [@title="American Football"]//span').text
    print(test)

    driver.quit()
```

That is what i am running as my test, i also tried without the with loop and used display.start() instead but same result. nothing.

I have installed Xvfb and other dependencies that pyvirtual says it needs and i get no error message at all it just feels like the code is skipping over it like its in a false if statement or something.

Why not use --headless?

For this test the headless DOES work as intended however on my "main" script the headless mode throws up multiple errors and seems like it is being blocked by site, basically i just want to use pyvirtual as i did before the SD card broke which just had virtual as you see above and selenium used it without --headless argument

Sorry for the long post but i am trying to give as much detail as i can, if anyone has anything they want to ask to expand on feel free. Thanks guys for taking the time i appreciate it :)

Python version: 3.11
Chromium version: 116.0.5845.102
Chromedriver version: Unknown but i used the apt install method and it works fine non-headless